# Squid 3.3.8 delay pool class 1 unexpected behaviour

Tags: proxy, delay, squid, bandwidth-throttling

I am trying to limit the bandwidth of a specific group of users using Squid 3.3. To accomplish this I have used the following delay pools configuration:

```
delay_pools 2
delay_class 1 1
delay_parameters 1 15000/30000

delay_class 2 1
delay_parameters 2 -1/-1

delay_access 1 allow users
delay_access 2 allow admins
```

I want to allow the simple "users" to share 15KBps and for the "admins" to have unlimited access.

However, this configuration works and sometimes it doesn't. Namely, when 2 users from the "users" acl group connect, they sometimes share the bandwidth i.e. 7,5KBps each and sometimes they receive 15KBps each.

What I expect is that when N users connect each will receive 15KBps/N bandwidth. Is this assumption correct? If not, I would be grateful if someone could guide me how to accomplish this.

Thank you in advance.